# Angular 5 validation error not shown on input change

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a problem with an input control where if I type 501 (not valid value) the mat-error is not shown unless input loses focus. How can I show it when the user types in an invalid value without input losing focus?
This is the html

```
<div class="col-auto form margin-top-17 margin-left-10" [formGroup]="activationPointsFormGroup">
            <mat-form-field style="width:230px!important">
                <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Range" [formControl]="activationPointsFormControl" 
                (keydown.enter)="loadData()">
                <mat-error class="margin-top-1" *ngIf="activationPointsFormControl.errors">
                    Valid values are between -500 and 500 and not 0
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

and the typescript code

```
  public activationPointsFormGroup: FormGroup;
  public activationPointsFormControl: FormControl;

  private createForm(): void {
        this.activationPointsFormControl = new FormControl(1, [Validators.required, Validators.min(-500), Validators.max(500)]);
        this.activationPointsFormGroup = new FormGroup({
            timeThresholdFormControl: this.activationPointsFormControl,
        });

        this.activationPointsFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {

            if (value) {
                this.selectedActivationPoints = value;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, you need an [**error state matcher**](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown), to customize the angular material validation behavior, import `ErrorStateMatcher` and...

```ts
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';

export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return !!(control && control.invalid && control.dirty);
  }
}
```

This will now show the error message when control is `dirty`. Declare a an error state matcher in your component...

```ts
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
```

and then mark it on your input field:

```ts
<input matInput [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" ...>
```

Here's a demo, which will show that email is not valid while user is typing...

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukd3n2?file=app/form-field-error-example.ts)